# Pandas concatenate to multi index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I got five DataFrames with the same index and column names, and I want to concatenate them in one DataFrame with a multi index with the previous index and the column names, and the new column names would be [ 'A', 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E'] ie the name of the DataFrames.

(I want to do that to export it as a np.array with 5 col and many rows, I tell you that because perhaps there is a better way to it.)

Thanks !!

EDIT :
I'll try to explain more clearly :
say we got only two df :

```
df1 = AA
    X   Y   Z
0   x0  y0  z0
1   x1  y1  z1
2   x2  y2  z2

df2 = BB
    X   Y   Z
0   x00 y00 z00
1   x11 y11 z11
2   x22 y22 z22
```

what I want is :

```
dfAll
        AA  BB
X   0   x0  x00
    1   x1  x11
    2   x2  x22
Y   0   y0  y00
    1   y1  y11
    2   y2  y22
Z   0   z0  z00
    1   z1  z11
    2   z2  z22
```

EDIT 2 :
I've manage to do it with

```
df1 = df1.stack()
df2 = df2.stack()
dfALL = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Thanks for you hints , it helps me thinking.

Comment: Please provide a sample of input data.

Comment: Unfortunately yesterday I dont check comments, so only a bit improved your nice solution in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` for `Multiindex`:

```
np.random.seed(234)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df5 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,3)), columns=list('ABC'))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], keys=['A', 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E'])
print (df)
     A  B  C
A 0  8  4  9
  1  1  3  7
  2  6  3  0
B 0  3  3  2
  1  6  8  9
  2  3  7  5
C 0  7  4  0
  1  0  7  5
  2  7  3  9
D 0  3  9  3
  1  3  4  4
  2  8  5  7
E 0  2  7  4
  1  9  3  9
  2  8  9  7
```

If want output `2d array` use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
arr = np.concatenate([df1.values, df2.values, df3.values, df4.values, df5.values])
print (arr)
[[8 4 9]
 [1 3 7]
 [6 3 0]
 [3 3 2]
 [6 8 9]
 [3 7 5]
 [7 4 0]
 [0 7 5]
 [7 3 9]
 [3 9 3]
 [3 4 4]
 [8 5 7]
 [2 7 4]
 [9 3 9]
 [8 9 7]]
```

EDIT: A bit improved your solution with parameter `keys`:

```
dfALL = pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()], axis=1, keys=('AA', 'BB'))
print (dfALL)
     AA   BB
0 X  x0  x00
  Y  y0  y00
  Z  z0  z00
1 X  x1  x11
  Y  y1  y11
  Z  z1  z11
2 X  x2  x22
  Y  y2  y22
  Z  z2  z22
```

Comment: Hellooo, nice to see you write an answer after a while.

Comment: @jezrael : the col names are not the df names.

Comment: @BPulsart - Can you explain more? Do you need 2d array? What are `A-E` ?

Comment: @BPulsart - If `A-E` are `name`s of DataFrames, then still need define `keys` as list, or use `df = pd.concat({'A':df1,'B':df2,'C':df3,'D':df4,'E':df5})`

Comment: @BPulsart - But still need define explicitely keys - in answer in list, in comment above as keys of dictionary of DataFrames.

Comment: @jezrael : iI got it, so I could be now more accurate : considering your answer, we will name the col XYZ so it's not confusing with the ABCDE of the df names. What I want is to have the col name XYZ as index and ABCDE as col name, and for now it's the opposite. How could I do that ? I've tried `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], keys=df1.columns.tolist())` so I got the right index but not the five col.

Comment: @jezrael :in fact no, I don't get the right index, just the first five, and all the previous col.

Comment: @BPulsart - So the best is remove my answer, because not helpful?